# How to apply Mantine styles.css only to React component(s) that exist "inside" a legacy web page?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, mantine

We are slowly migrating a legacy (non-React) web application built on top of Bootstrap 4.x to a React based framework. Our strategy involves replacing various elements of each page with React components until we can finally replace the entire page with a top level React app.

That said, we are wanting to use Mantine as our core component library and cannot figure out how to only apply the Mantine `styles.css` to our React components.

By inserting the the line `import '@mantine/core/styles.css'` in our React components, it still applies the styles globally - changing the look and feel of non-React page sections. Is there a way to only apply the Mantine styles.css locally to a single React component?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if we instead import the Mantine styles.css (it's actually `index.css`) at the top level of our scss file, then we can have the Bootstrap styling override any conflicts. This seems to have solved the issue for now.

For example:
main.scss

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------
   Vendor Imports
   ---------------------------------------------------------*/
@import "../node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/index.css";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "../node_modules/selectize-bootstrap4-theme/scss/selectize.bootstrap4.scss";
```